# Typescript complaining property x does not exist on type '{ data: () =>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, axios, interface

I get this error message in my console:

ERROR in src/components/Dashboard.vue:20:32
TS2339: Property 'fetchAllProducts' does not exist on type '{ data: () => { products: Product[]; }; mounted(): Promise; methods: { fetchAllProducts(): Promise; };
}'.

```
    18 |     }),
    19 |     async mounted() {
  > 20 |         const res = await this.fetchAllProducts();
       |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    21 |         this.products = res;
    22 |         console.log(res)
    23 |     },
```

ERROR in src/components/Dashboard.vue:21:14
TS2339: Property 'products' does not exist on type '{ data: () => { products: Product[]; }; mounted(): Promise; methods: { fetchAllProducts(): Promise; }; }'.

```
    19 |     async mounted() {
    20 |         const res = await this.fetchAllProducts();
  > 21 |         this.products = res;
       |              ^^^^^^^^
    22 |         console.log(res)
    23 |     },
    24 |     methods: {
```

My code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Product } from '@/types/types';
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        products: [] as Product[]
    }),
    async mounted() {
        const res = await this.fetchAllProducts();
        this.products = res;
        console.log(res)
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchAllProducts(){
            try {
                const res = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
                return res.data;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The code itself works, how to make the TS stop to cry?

Comment: Please share the code of `Dashboard.vue`

Comment: updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vue 2 you should create your component using `Vue.extend` helper :

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Product } from '@/types/types';
import axios from 'axios'
import Vue from 'vue';


export default Vue.extend({
    data: () => ({
        products: [] as Product[]
    }),
    async mounted() {
        const res = await this.fetchAllProducts();
        this.products = res;
        console.log(res)
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchAllProducts(){
            try {
                const res = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
                return res.data;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

for Vue 3 use `defineComponent`